# csc_picker package in flutter web not clickable

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

csc_picker package in flutter web not clickable.

Here is what the error shows:

> Flutter Web engine failed to fetch
> "assets/packages/csc_picker/lib/assets/country.json". HTTP request
> succeeded, but the server responded with HTTP status 404.

Can anyone enlighten me what is thee problem with this one?

I cannot click the fields